# Unable to get Images from AWS-S3 bucket in django-app?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS-S3 to store my users' profile images. I've repeated this process 7-8 times but when I open my app on local machine(I've not deployed it yet) the user profile images aren't there and it shows the alt='not found' in place of images.

I've made a user in IAM and a bucket in S3 same as in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt3ZtW9MXhw&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=16) tutorial nearly 5 times but there's no way I'm getting the images.

Also when I right click on any image in my app and go into the image location I'm getting this in my browser.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
        `AccessDenied`Access Denied6683BC64F8FCAB0CE2foYctY9f7GMW+VI64vr3rRfMPrXXGfscryk3Eqo7meEtenXCLSa4kGYnQBJV6qDG9AdBVVgR8=

Here's my `settings.py` file

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'myblog/media')

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blogapp.apps.BlogappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myblog.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'max_similarity': 1,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blogapp/static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blogapp:post_list'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'djangoblogapp'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

In absence of S3 the app works fine but using AWS the images aren't getting loaded. I've downloaded boto3 and django-storages and using django 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a CORS issue from the S3 side, see the [docs from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html). You will need to have a CORS configuration for the bucket to allow non-S3-console sites to see the files (you are getting a fairly generic XML empty response).

You will need to go to the permissions tab for your bucket, then CORS configuration, and enter something like the policies from the link, eg a very basic one that should allow you to use your images as you want would look like:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

but if you need something more sophisticated/limiting then the docs there are pretty good.

Comment: I'm getting the same message even after putting up the CORS configuration in my bucket. I've deleted the user and bucket 5 times and created the new one and used the new one with new ACCESS_KEY and ID but still the images aren't getting in my app. What to do?

Comment: no need to keep remaking buckets and users! Could well be your bucket policy in that case - do you only need your instances/account to access the images or do they need to be public? many examples here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html